# scrapy parse_item method is not getting called

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is my code. My parse_item method is not getting called.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class SjsuSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'sjsu'
    allowed_domains = ['sjsu.edu']
    start_urls = ['http://cs.sjsu.edu/']
    # allow=() is used to match all links
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True),
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print "some message"
        open("sjsupages", 'a').write(response.body)
```

Comment: do you have to specify a value for allow?? i'd think that your spider is not finding any items to parse.

Comment: I dont know...but that makes sense..what can I put in allow if I want to scrap everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your allowed domain should be `'cs.sjsu.edu'`.

Scrapy does not allow subdomains of an allowed domain.

Also, your rules could be written as:

```
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]
```

Comment: should it not be rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback=self.parse_item)] ??

Comment: `self.parse_item` wouldn't work, as `self` is not in scope in the class definition. So 'parse_item' as a string is sensible.